# Not able to push database results into a list in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

```
fetch(sql) {
    let answer = [];
    db.execute(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("From DB");
        answer.push(result);
    });
    return answer;
}

let sql = "SELECT * from employees";
let result = fetch(sql);
console.log(result);
```

When I call this fetch function, I get an empty list. I want that the results should be pushed into the list first and then the list should be returned.
All the db configurations are correct and the results are being fetched but they are not pushed into the list.

Answer (score -1):

`db.execute` is an asynchroneous function. So you return `answer` which you initialized as an empty array before `db.execute` finishes. Therefore it's always empty. You need to wait for `db.execute` to complete. To do so, you could use a promise structure like this:

```
fetchDbResults(sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.execute(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

const sql = "SELECT * from employees";
fetchDbResults(sql).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```